# How can I unite 1D arrays in numpy in 2D one?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3 arrays

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([6,7,8,9,10])
c = np.array([11,12,13,14,15])
```

How can I unite it to get

```
abc = [[1,6,11]
       [2,7,12]
       [3,8,13]
       [4,9,14]
       [5,10,15]]
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
abc = np.array([a, b, c]).transpose()
```

How does this work?

`np.array([a, b, c])` creates a new numpy array with the **rows** equal to a, b and c:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

However, since you want the **columns** to be equal to a, b and c, we need to "flip" the matrix along the diagonal, which is achieved by calling `transpose()`. This produces the desired result:

```
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Comment: Or just `abc = np.array([a, b, c].T`